# submit button disabled when logging in a user

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I am making the logging in functionality and for some reason when I
 fill in all the input fields my button stays disabled and I cant submit it.

this is the renderButton function...

```
renderButton(label) {
  return (
    <button
      disabled={this.validate() ? true : false}
      className="btn btn-primary"
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
}
```

this is the login form...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Form from "./form";
import { login } from "../services/authService";

class LoginForm extends Form {
  state = {
    data: { username: "", password: "" },
    errors: {}
  };

  schema = {
    email: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Email"),
    password: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Password")
  };

  doSubmit = async () => {
    //call server
    const { data } = this.state;
    await login(data.email, data.password);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.renderInput("email", "Email")}
          {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
          {this.renderButton("Login")}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

this is the validation functions where both validate and vaidate property is in it...

```
validate = () => {
   const options = { abortEarly: false };
   const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options);
   if (!error) return null;

   const errors = {};
   for (let item of error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
   return errors;
 };

 validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
   const obj = { [name]: value };
   const schema = { [name]: this.schema[name] };
   const { error } = Joi.validate(obj, schema);
   return error ? error.details[0].message : null;
 };
```

Comment: Where is `validate` function?

Comment: i added the two functions to the code above

Comment: Trigger validate function on input changes. Add a disabled field which defaults to true and make it false if there are no errors in validate function. You can achieve the same by using this.state.errors to toggle button active state. But adding a disabled field to your state makes it much more cleaner IMHO. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the render function is not called each time your input changes, maybe it is because you are extending some Form and not React. It is anti pattern to make a deep nesting, just extend React, if you want to add some functionality you can wrap your component with HOC (higher order component function).